# why does this error keep popping up? Missing { inserted. \end{align}

Tags: equations

so, this is my code:

```
\begin{align*}
$$  
\nonumber
f'(x) &= \lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} \\ \nonumber 
&= \lim_{x\to c}\frac{cos(x)-cos(c)}{x-c} \\\nonumber 
&= \lim_{x\to c}\frac{-2sin\frac{x+c}{2}sin\frac{x-c}{2}}{x-c} \\ \nonumber 
&= -sinc
$$
\end{align*}
```

it keeps sending me this error:

> ```
>  Missing { inserted. \end{align}
> ```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What are those `$$` supposed to do? Remove them and also all `\nonumber` calls.

Comment: Without them, my equation is not in math mode, so it's not centred, andif i remove \nonumber, after each line, the line will be numbered

Comment: Did you *try*? By the way you should type `\cos` and `\sin`

Comment: No `align*` starts math mode so the `$$` is an error.

Comment: @KatarinaGrgić I am not getting an error. What document class are you using?

Comment: It's in an article, so i'm using documentclass{article}

Answer (score 2):

Use `align*` *without* `$$` as it is already set in math mode:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]
\begin{align*}
  f'(x) &= \lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x - c} \\
        &= \lim_{x \to c} \frac{\cos(x) - \cos(c)}{x - c} \\
        &= \lim_{x \to c} \frac{-2 \sin \frac{x + c}{2} \sin \frac{x - c}{2}}{x - c} \\
        &= -\sin c
\end{align*}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Note the use of `\sin` and `\cos` rather than just typing `sin` and `cos`. The latter two are interpreted as symbol multiplications (`s` times `i` times `n`), not as an operator.